# How to force a full rebuild in Xcode 13?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm currently testing an onboarding flow in my app and I right now I'm having to delete the app from the simulator and build it anew with (cmd+r for mac).

Is there a shortcut that exists to get the simulator to delete the app itself and fully rebuild?

edit: I'm having to delete as I'm saving things into `UserDefault` with `AppStorage`

Comment: Just delete userdefaults in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate

Comment: Cool! I'll take a look at this, thank you

Comment: If just user defaults and app storage, usually just deleting the app from the device/simulator is sufficient. Resetting the whole simulator/device is overkill for most scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Simulator

### Device > Erase All Content and Settings

That's the quickest way to give you a totally reset simulator ready for a clean app install.

Comment: awesome! thank you